# Expected type did not match the received type

Tags: rust, quicksort

I'm new to rust, and I'm trying to get my hands dirty, so I'm trying to implement quicksort, as part of one of the exercises of "The Book" ( probably the writer didn't intend to suggest to go this deep though, but isn't it the best way to learn? :) )

this is what I have so far:

```
fn quicksort(v: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    // helper funtions for sorting the partitional vectors
    
    fn partition(v: &mut Vec<i32>, lo: i32, hi: i32) {
    // pivot
    let mut p: i32;
    let mut i = lo;

    for j in i..hi {
    }
    }
    
    fn quicksort(v: &mut Vec<i32>, lo: i32, hi: i32) {
    // pivot
    let mut p: i32;
    if lo < hi {
        p = partition(v, lo, hi);
    }
    }


    quicksort(v, 0, (v.len() -1).try_into().unwrap())
}
```

when I try to compile I get this:

```
[foo12@archT520 vectors]$ cargo run
   Compiling vectors v0.1.0 (/home/foo12/programs/rust/book/vectors)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:36:10
   |
36 |         p = partition(v, lo, hi);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `i32`, found `()`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `vectors`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I don't see what I'm screwing up.

---

Also, I'd be glad to get a complete implementation of quicksort which doesn't use other libraries. Probably I could learn from it.

---

EDIT: I'm also not sure if this way of "shadowing" with the function name "quicksort" is going to work. I changed it before, so it's not the cause of the error, but I'd like to see if it's going to work this way, that's why I left it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fn partition(v: &mut Vec<i32>, lo: i32, hi: i32)` is not returning anything (denoted in Rust as having the return type `()`), so you cannot assign the result to a variable of type `i32`.

Comment: duuuuuhhhhhh...... thanks! I kept thinking that the arguments having the issue :D